# "Error: Unknown command 'tap'"

Tags: php, installation, upgrade, homebrew

I try to upgrade the PHP version to 5.4.4, which apparently isn't the most simple thing todo.

However, I found [this link](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php), which provides the following command:

```
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

...which is supposed to do the trick.

However, when running the command in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown command 'tap'
```

I can't find any information about this error and according to the installation instructions it should work because I have Homebrew installed.

So, any clues? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's an error by `brew` or from your terminal? Can you post the complete command and output?

Comment: Did you go through the [common issues](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php#common-issues) one-by-one yet to rule out any of those?

Comment: @deceze: Actually I don't know. The input is "brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php" and the output is "Error: Unknown command 'tap'"

Comment: @TimCooper: Yes, none of the things there's helped me.